# Text in textbox save in Notpade

Tags: c#

Can anyone please help me? I am new in C#.
I write text in TextBox1 and when i click button "Open" then text i like to save in notepad.?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. Please add more detail as to what _exactly_ you are trying to do.

Comment: where are you blocked? What did you try? How do you want to achieve it? who taught you English (I had to edit your question, please check it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) method which allows you to write some text to a new file. For example:

```
string text = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text;
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\file.txt", text);
```

Comment: huuhuu it was so easy.  i trying any form :S..Thenk you so much. You save me :)